# inastall @agm-core on angular14

Tags: angular, google-maps, npm, angular14, agm-core

**when trying to install agm-core, get error**

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: undefined@undefined
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@14.0.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"^14.0.4" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^9.1.0 || ^10.0.0" from @agm/core@3.0.0-beta.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@agm/core
npm ERR!   @agm/core@"^3.0.0-beta.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @agm/core@"^3.0.0-beta.0" from @angular-material-extensions/google-maps-autocomplete@8.1.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-material-extensions/google-maps-autocomplete
npm ERR!     @angular-material-extensions/google-maps-autocomplete@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-07-05T09_18_32_425Z-debug-0.log

Comment: what command you are using to install `@agm`?

Comment: npm install @agm/core

Answer (score 4):

You could try to install agm/core with `--legacy-peer-deps`. This is because this npm package contains outdated requirements for older Angular versions (version <=8) and that aborts the install.

```
npm install @agm/core --legacy-peer-deps
```

Answer (score 3):

After the frustration of waiting for an update on `@agm/core` for years (the last release was 3 years ago), I forked and made an Angular 14-compatible version myself ([package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hudsontavares/agm-core)).

All you need to do is to run `npm i @hudsontavares/agm-core` and replace the `@agm/core` references inside your code.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome work, im getting this error: Error: node_modules/@hudsontavares/agm-core/lib/services/google-maps-api-wrapper.d.ts:51:41 - error TS2314: Generic type 'MapHandlerMap<T>' requires 1 type argument(s)."

Comment: @mahen23 - thanks for pointing it out. That's probably related to the package version for `@types/googlemaps.`

I have it on version `^3.39.8` on a working repository. Please confirm if changing that in your repository fixes this issue. In the positive case, I'll update the README with this step AND my answer above.

Comment: Works great, thanks for the awesome work again, having lots of issues with Capacitor Google maps.